# Complex integrals of $1/(z+a)$ over the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

In quite a few questions here, it has been settled that
$$
  \int_C \frac{1}{z} dz = 2\pi i
$$
where $C$ is the unit circle with the origin at its center. I also understand how to think about this, using that the complex logarithm has a branch cut on the positive real axis, so $\log{1}$ takes different values in the two limits.

My problem arises with integrals like
$$
  \int_C \frac{1}{z+3} dz = 0
$$
From the Cauchy Residue theorem it clear that the integral is $0$, but I can't get that result when doing the integral explicitly:

$$
  \int_C \frac{1}{z+3} dz = \left[ \log{(e^{i\phi} + 3)} \right]_0^{2\pi}
$$

Using the argument from the first integral above, the answer should be $2\pi i$. Obviously that's not right, but why?

Comment: "Using the argument from the first integral above, the answer should be 2πi" Well... no. Why do you think "the argument from the first integral above" implies that? Please be specific.

Comment: @Did In the first integral of $1/z$, the direct integration yields $\log{e^{2\pi i}} - \log{e^{0}}$. Using branch cuts, we get that the result of this is $2\pi i$, even though "naively" we would expect 0. Doing the same in the second integral we get $\log{(e^{2\pi i}+3)} - \log{(e^{0}+3}$. So why do we not see branch cuts here? Why is the result 0, when it wasn't before?

Comment: The branch cut is $\{x+iy\mid x\leqslant0,y=0\}$. You are integrating on the circle of center $3$ and radius $1$. Again: why do you think the former is relevant to the latter?

Comment: @Did I'm sorry, I cant explain my problem better than I already did. I accepted the answer below. Thanks for your help in any case!

Comment: Too bad. The road to non-improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Using the residue theorem, the integral is also $0$, because that theorem says that the integral is the product of $3$ numbers:

- $2\pi i$
- the residue at $-3$ (which is $1$);
- the winding number of the loop around the origin $t\mapsto e^{it}$ ($t\in[0,2\pi]$), which is $0$.

Since the last number is $0$, the product is $0$.

Comment: I understand that the integral is supposed to be 0. My confusion is that I evaluate the logarithms $\log{(e^{2\pi i} + 3)}$ and $\log{(e^{0} + 3)}$, which are both on the positive real axis just like the integral of $1/z$. So why don't I get different values for the logarithms now? Why are the two logarithms equal?

Comment: @ChristianWaltherAndersen Why do you say they're different? After all, $e^{2\pi i}=e^0=1$.

Comment: @GNUSupporter I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, of course, but that was not allowed in the integral of $1/z$, so why is it ok to say so now?

Comment: @ChristianWaltherAndersen Because now we are are working with a single branch of the logarithm. Now, the point that causes trouble (which is $0$) is far from the regiion where we are making the integration. In the case of the integral of $1/z$, it's in the middle of it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I guess another way of phrasing my question is: Why does $e^{0}$ and $e^{2\pi i}$ live on different branch cuts of the logarithm, but not $e^{0}+3$ and $e^{2\pi i} + 3$? Does that make sense?

Comment: @ChristianWaltherAndersen Yes (although I don't think in terms of branch cuts). In the case of $\frac1z$, you have a loop around $0$; there is no holomorphic branch of the logarithm there. But in that other case, you can simply take the main branch of the logarithm.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Okay. I think you've at least pushed me in a direction of understanding this, although its still puzzling me a bit. Thanks!